# Is there a way to display a macro list similar to displaying your mappings in Vim?

Tags: macros, vim, vi

I know there is a way to list mappings via `:map` (or `:imap`, `:cmap`, etc.), but I can't find a way to list macros I have stored in my vimrc file (as in `let @a = 'blahblah'`).

Is there a way to do this without having to manually looking inside it (via `:split [myvimrcfile]` or whatever way)?

Also, if it is possible, is there a way to attach some sort of documentation that would display with the macro to explain what it is for? I have a handful that I use quite a bit, but about 6 weeks apart. It would be nice to just quickly list them along with a comment that tells me what the macro does (or even just a name so I make sure I use the right one).

Thanks

Comment: This could be useful for writing mappings.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In vim, the macros are just stored in  [`registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).  You can recall the content of any register and execute it as a macro (which is what the `@` does).  To see a list of what is in your registers, use [`:reg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:reg).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't list the macro in the register unless I recall it first. I'd want to know what the macro I've mapped to that register is before I run it (so I know which one to run).

Comment: Really?  For things I have in my `.vimrc` (as `let @a=blah`), I am able to see them when I first start up (gVim 7.2).  Do you have a function or script that you have to execute to set your macros?

Comment: I am also using gVim7.2. I just typed my macros directly into my vimrc file... although it is in c:\program files\vim\vimfiles\vimrc_Jay.vim which is loaded in my _vimrc file via source $VIM/vimfiles/vimrc_Jay.vim. Do you think that's the issue?

Comment: I just tried moving them into my _vimrc file instead of my other vimrc_Jay file, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: They seem to be working now (after switching everything back to my original setup). I'm not sure what changed and I didn't run all of them, so I know it's not from recalling that register first. Oh well. Your answer DOES work. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it's working for you...  Be sure to post if you figure out why it wasn't working at first or if you find any issues with it.

Comment: Also works for me, even in IntelliJ's vim mode

Answer (score 6):

You can see the contents of all the registers using the

```
:reg
```

command. Or an argument string like this

```
:reg ahx
```

will show you the contents of registers a, h, and x.

That way you can at least see what sequence of commands will be run and hopefully that will be clear enough for you to tell one from another.

The registers simply contain text. You can paste the command sequence in as text or you can copy text into a register and then run it as a command, depending on how you access the register.

I have not found any direct way to edit the contents of a register, but you can paste it into the file, edit it, and then save it back to the same register.

IHTH.

Answer (score 3):

As [/u/jheddings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197772/jheddings) wrote the macros are stored as registers and what counts is the assignment of the code to the register (usually done in the vimrc files with `let @a=blahblah`
To ease the way to display the macros you defined in your vimrc file (in my case it is in the ~/.vimrc path) you can use this vim function:

```
function! ShowMacros()
    10new
    exe 'r!' . 'grep -B 1 -E "^\s*let @" ~/.vimrc'
    call cursor(1,1)
endfunction
```

What it does:

`10new` - open a new vim window with ten lines size

`exe ...` - execute a command and put in the window

`call ...` - go to the first line first column

You can execute this function by tipping in the normal mode
`:call ShowMacros`

You could additionally create a key mapping or a command to fasten the way to call the function:

```
:cnoremap sm call ShowMacros()<CR>
command!  sm call ShowMacros()`
```

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1031796/import-previous-commands-to-edited-command) is the original post where I wrote the function similar to the above.

Comment: :s/tipping/typing/  |  
:s/fasten/speed up/ (or "hasten", but that's archaic)

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked, "is there a way to attach some sort of documentation that would display with the macro to explain what it is for?"

I have found VI / VIM macros extremely obtuse to understand even a week after I've written them, so I heartily support the idea of documentation. I have a suggestion for that, in two parts.

First is the process of documenting the macro in your `.vimrc`. I've developed the following `.vimrc` comment format that helps me understand, a week or a year or more later, what a macro is supposed to be doing. E.g.:

```
"
"= GENERIC CLIPBOARD YANK  <F2>y (Y for Yank)
"= Yank the entire contents of the file into the clipboard; quit without saving.
"
"define F2 followed by y to be:
"|      Go to line 1.
"|      | From there, into the * buffer (system clipboard),
"|      | | yank to the end of the file.
"|      | | | Go to sleep for 1 second (to allow the clipboard to be updated).
"|      | | | |  Quit without saving the file.
"|      | | | |  |
map #2y 1G"*yG1gs:q!<CR>
"-------"-"-"-"--"------
```

Second, I am imagining that Jakub's `ShowMacros()` function above could be modified to `grep` a specific set of Help lines for each macro that would be in the file along with the definition, much the way the above command-line breakdown is attached to the definition, that would provide the needed User Help.

I've flagged two lines above with `"=` at the beginning of each, so that they can become the User Help. Then Jakub's `grep` command would search for `"^\"= "`. Here's the command I used. I'm not sure if the `-E` for Extended Regular Expressions is needed and the `-B 1` is a nice touch to include one line previous to a matching sequence, so here I have an explicitly empty comment line.

In my `vimrc`, I only needed one backslash, for the initial parsing of the definitions. Here's the line, replacing the one in Jakub's function definition above:

```
    exe 'r!' . 'grep -B 1 -E "^\"= " ~/.vimrc'
```

Thanks to Jakub's hint, I now can generate help from my `.vimrc` in pretty much exactly the way the OP is asking for. I've been using `vi` since 1983, so I'm pretty stoked.

Thanks Jakub!

IHTH,

August